# query remote OS using computer name instead of IP

Tags: c#

I want to get the OS using the computer name instead of the ip address.  Below is the source using the ip address, how can I modify it using the computer name?

```
public string GetOsVersion(string ipAddress)
{
using (var reg = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, ipAddress))
using (var key = reg.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\"))
{
   return string.Format("{0}", key.GetValue("ProductName"));
    }
    }
```

The code above works using the IP but doesn't work using the computer name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zha3xws%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you should just be able to use computer name in place of ipAddress. Is the remote computer accessible via the computer name?

Comment: string RemoteOSversion = (GetOsVersion(computername)); doesn't work for me

Comment: You could try adding and entry into your hosts file depending on what you are really trying to accomplish. If the ip address may change then this might not be the best solution. Is the remote computer located on the same network as the local computer?